# Microsoft Edge: How to undo last password sync?

Tags: passwords, sync, microsoft-edge

So I logged in to Edge Sync with my work mail address, on a private device. Now all the passwords stored on this device are synced to my work email which is very unfortunate. I wanted to keep business and private accounts seperate.

Is there any way to undo this last password sync?

If not, is there any way to remove the passwords from all websites, except those containing specific words (name of employer) ?

Comment: You will have to stop synchronizing passwords then likely wipe the passwords that were synchronized.  This likely would have to be manually.

Comment: Hmm that's unfortunate. But so be it..